# Find the smallest $n$ with $(113^{13})^n \equiv 113 \bmod 155$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the smallest $n$ with $(113^{13})^n \equiv 113 \bmod  155$

My thoughts:
Since the multiplicative ring $\mathbb{Z}_{155}$ has $155$ elements, then $a^{155}= 1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ 
Hence $113^{155} \equiv 1 \bmod  155$
Then I noticed that $12 \cdot 13=155+1$ and hence $n=12$, but I don't know how to check this. Is this correct? Is there any algorithm to find $n$ in more complicated cases?

Comment: Does $12$ work?  working $\pmod 5$ we see $113\equiv 3\pmod 5$ and $13\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ so $113^{13}\equiv 3^1\equiv 3 \pmod 5$ and $3^{12}\equiv 1\pmod 5$.

Comment: More broadly, I suggest solving the problem $\pmod 5$ and $\pmod {31}$.  Always easier to work with smaller numbers.

Comment: No $a^{155}\equiv 1\pmod {155}$ just take $a=115$

Comment: So, for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ is wrong

Comment: You misapplied Lagrange's theorem. The entire ring is not a group. Rather the unit group of all elements coprime to $155$ has size $\phi(155) = \phi(5)\phi(31) = 4(30) = 120$, where $\phi = $ Euler totient.

Comment: In general,  the *nonzero* elements of a ring form a *multiplicative monoid*, but not necessarily a group.   If it forms a group (every nonzero element is a unit) you have a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(113,155)=1,$ we can divide out $113.$  Get $113^{13n-1}\equiv 1\pmod {155}.$

By Euler's theorem,  $113^{\varphi (155)}\equiv 113^{120}\equiv 1\pmod {155}.$

So the order of $113\pmod {155}$ divides $120$.  It's easy to check that that order is $60.$

So, $60\mid(13n-1)\implies n=37.$

(I found $13^{-1}\equiv 37\pmod {60}$ by some *twiddling*.  You could also use the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Comment: I think you mean $n=37$.

Comment: 1. Is $120$ the smallest positive integer $m$ satisfying $113^m \equiv 1 \pmod{155}$? It may or may not be as far as I know, but either way it does need to be established IMO. 2. I don't think $120$ divides $(13 \cdot 27) -1$ as even $3$ does not divide $(13 \cdot 27)-1$.

Comment: You're right.   @J.G.

Comment: Right @Mike. I also decided that it didn't need to be established.

Comment: **Error** The inference in the third line assumes that $113$ has order $120,\,$ mod $115$. The correct order is $60$.  But - by luck - the answer is correct even though the argument is not, because $13^{-1}\bmod 60 = 37\,$ too, and $\,37 < 60\,$ so it's the least inverse $\!\bmod 60\,$ (which fails if the order was a divisor of $120$ that's $< 37)\ \ $

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the only other choice is $n = 1$"?  The correct answer is $\,n = 13^{-1}\bmod{k},\,$ where $k =$ order of $ 113\pmod{155}.\,$ Here $\,k = 60.\,$ In any case this question is a dupe of a FAQ so should not have been answered. It will likely be deleted,

Comment: Thanks for the correction  @BillDubuque. See my edit.